# What does "kind of way" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain the phrase in bold for me, please?

> On Thursday, too, the Bank of Japan pushed back its inflation target for the sixth time and kept interest rates steady. The bank's monetary policy has "completely gone off the rails **in a scorched earth kind of way**," Peter Boockvar, chief market analyst at The Lindsey Group, wrote in a Thursday note to clients.

<sup>([Source: CNBC](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/07/20/are-investors-losing-their-faith-in-the-central-banks.html))</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In a(n) X kind of way* is the same as an adverb in the form of "X-ly", which answers the question "how is X done?"

> I looked at her wistfully.
>
> I looked at her in a wistful kind of way.

This construct allow a well-known descriptive phrase or idiom to answer the same question "how is X done" instead of a single word.

Here's an example that isn't the best but hopefully illustrates:

> I burned bridges with my boss and quit without notice.
>
> I quit my job in a bridge burning kind of way.  (Bridge-burningly generally won't work.)

Answer (score 2):

**kind of way** is colloquial phrase that is used when the speaker is making a comparison that is not "spot on" or perfectly apt but is a rough approximation or "fuzzy" in some other way, perhaps an exaggeration, and the speaker is acknowledging that fact:

> She gave him a kiss, but it was in a grandmotherly kind of way.
>
> He plays poker in a taking-no-prisoners kind of way.

It might be paraphrased "sort of in that manner".

**sort of** and **kind of** are qualifiers bordering on partial disclaimer.